# Bulk insert into MySQL on duplicate

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python

I have a question in MySQL and Python MySQLdb library:

Suppose I'd like to insert a bulk in to the DB. When I'm inserting, there are possibly a duplicated among the records in the bulk, or a record in the bulk may be a duplicate of a record in the table. In case of duplicates, I'd like to ignore the duplication and just insert the rest of the bulk. In case of a duplication in within the bulk, I'd like that only one of the records (any of them) will be inserted, and the rest of the bulk will also be inserted.

How can I write it in MySQL syntax? And is it built-in in MySQLdb library in Python?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - Make your initial insert into a staging table.

Step 2 - deal with duplicate records and all other issues.

Step 3 - write to your real tables from the staging table.

Comment: Is it more efficient than checking each record by select before a bulk insert?

Comment: Depends on the details, but probably not.